# Convert hex string hash to base64

Tags: string, groovy, hash, base64, hex

I have a plaintext password "welcome2022".

Expected SHA1 hash is `wjC4KfO5XfMIRhi45M/VA/0i8NA=`

However, SHA1 hash method of sql is generating SHA1 hash in hex string format which is `C230B829F3B95DF3084618B8E4CFD503FD22F0D0`.

I intend to convert  the the above hex string to the base64 encoded hash `wjC4KfO5XfMIRhi45M/VA/0i8NA=`.

Below is the groovy code for your reference.

```
    def cleartext = SecurityUtil.decrypt(password) //Decrypts the value of a GuardedString.    
   def password_bytes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] as byte[]
    password_bytes = SecurityUtil.charsToBytes(cleartext.toCharArray())
    def password2 = SecurityUtil.computeBase64SHA1Hash(password_bytes) //Computes the base 64 encoded SHA1 hash of the input.
```

Then running the below sql query,

```
sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName = ? AND password =CONCAT('{SHA1}', ?)", [username, password2]) {
....
}
```

Logs do not show any errors when this groovy script is executed.

I am not sure if I am writing the code correct syntactically.

Comment: Why would you need to convert a hex string to base64? What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: @Bill I am trying to validate a given plaintext password (welcome22) with a given hash which is wjC4KfO5XfMIRhi45M/VA/0i8NA=

Comment: I am not a groovy programmer, but if there are no errors the next thing that comes to mind is that there is no row of data that matches the inputs you show. Have you tried querying your database directly in a mysql client to confirm the row you expect is actually present?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right value you have? `"welcome22".digest('SHA-1').decodeHex().encodeBase64()` gives me `B3u0fGTNXOkEVM7C5pLo2ZHhFNc=`

Comment: @tim_yates yes. I was able to generrate this same hash value using java class messagedigest(giving a result of byte array) and base64 encode on the result byte array.

Comment: And according to https://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha1 checking the sha1 hash and https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex checking the encoded base64, Groovy is right with the above

Comment: @KaranNayyar I can only assume there's some sort of padding going on

Comment: @tim_yates Sorry I made a mistake here. The plaintext password was welcome2022.I updated the question.

Comment: @KaranNayyar ahhhhh... answer below then 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this function will give you the base64 encoded SHA-1 hash of a given password:

```
def sha64(String password) {
    password.digest('SHA-1').decodeHex().encodeBase64()
}
```

And if you do:

```
println sha64('welcome2022')
```

It prints

```
wjC4KfO5XfMIRhi45M/VA/0i8NA=
```